# MatLab Numerically Solving ODE for Circuit Problems

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode, ode45

So I am trying to solve numerically an ODE for a pretty simple circuit. In series Voltage source, Resistor, Capacitor 1, Capacitor 2 and then Inductor.

I have found the the values as R=2ohm, C1=3, C2=4 and Inductor=1 and Vin = 12e^(-0.5t) I am now trying to solve the ODE in MatLab numerically for
the input voltage so i can make a plot but i just cant get it.

I have tried manipulating a few examples from class and also going over some of the material but i am just not understanding if someone could help it would be much appreciated.

My current matlab reads:

```
[tcir2,ycir2] = ode45(@(t,y) [1/L*(12*exp(-0.5*t)-y(1)*R-y(2));y(1)/C],[0 10],[0 0]);
figure
plot(tcir2,ycir2)
```

with the values of respective variables plugged in.

Comment: If your circuit only has linear components, it can be solved analytically. If so, why would you want to solve it numerically?

Comment: well I have just been asked to solve it in MatLab. I am thinking would i need to make different equations for the different capacitors

Comment: and solve them individually in matlab and show them on the same plot

Comment: Please make your code self-contained; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.